# How to sum non-null values from multiple columns (workaround for CASE WHEN limitation) Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, case

So I essentially want to work around the fact that CASE WHEN stops executing when it finds its first TRUE return.

I'd like to sum every instance of a non-null value between multiple columns, and group these based on my ID. Example table:

| id | input1 | input2 | input3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | null | k |
| 2 | null | null | b |
| 3 | null | null | null |
| 4 | q | null | r |
| 5 | x | p | j |
| 6 | null | y | q |

I would like the output of my function to be:

| id | total_inputs |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 2 |

Any work arounds?  Is a custom function in order to create a count of unique or non-null entries across multiple columns, grouped by row?

I know I can create a CTE and assign 1's to each non-null column but that seems tedious (my data set has 39 inputs) - and I'd like to have a reusable function I could use again in the future.

Comment: I did the method of the extra-CTE and its functional- but inelegant. Would appreciate better methods.


with messy_CTE AS(
SELECT id
               , case when input1 is not null then 1 else 0 end as a
               , case when input2 is not null then 1 else 0 end as b
               , case when input3 is not null then 1 else 0 end as c
FROM my_table
)
    select id, a + b + c from messy_CTE

etc. etc. 

But again my data set is quite large. Don't love this method.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple aggregation as the following:

```
Select id, 
       Count(input1) + Count(input2) + Count(input3) As total_inputs
From table_name
Group By id
Order By id
```

Noting that Count(inputX) = 0, where inputX is null.

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/uEVwhONM).

Answer (score 0):

We can simply use:

```
select ID,
       case when input1 is not null then 1 else 0 end 
     + case when input2 is not null then 1 else 0 end 
     + ...
     + case when input39 is not null then 1 else 0 end as total_inputs
from ...
```

No need to group by if you want every row (or count, we are not aggregating rows - that is what COUNT()..GROUP BY is for), or CTE.

Also, for some PostgreSQL versions, there is a num_nulls function to count null parameters:

```
select
  , 32-num_nulls(input1, input2, input3, ..., input32)
```